# Sentry is alerting duplicate errors on every deploy

Tags: sentry

Currently, Sentry is alerting of the same issue on every deployment. How can I modify this setting to have a sentry alert in some time interval?
for example: if the error is appearing more frequently, then alert in an interval of time rather than wait for the next deployment and then alert about it.

thanks for your help.

Comment: You get two alerts for the same issue? What sdk are you using?

Comment: No, if the issue is repeating then only after another deployment it's alerting. but I want to have an alert when the same issue comes after an interval, it should alert not just on another deployment.